# Spring JPA javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class as follows:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "view")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class View {

    @Column(name = "widget_id")
    private int widgetId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "view_id")
    private int viewId;

    @Column(name = "view_name")
    private String viewName;

    @Column(name = "view_label")
    private String viewLabel;

    @Column(name = "view_type")
    private String viewType;

    @Column(name = "product")
    private String product;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updation_date",insertable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updationDate;

    public int getViewId() {
        return viewId;
    }

    public String getViewName() {
        return viewName;
    }

    public String getViewLabel() {
        return viewLabel;
    }

    public void setWidgetId(int widgetId) {
        this.widgetId = widgetId;
    }

    public void setViewId(int viewId) {
        this.viewId = viewId;
    }

    public void setViewName(String viewName) {
        this.viewName = viewName;
    }

    public void setViewLabel(String viewLabel) {
        this.viewLabel = viewLabel;
    }

    public void setViewType(String viewType) {
        this.viewType = viewType;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public String getViewType() {
        return viewType;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public Date getUpdationDate() {
        return updationDate;
    }
}
```

In my view table, that I have mentioned above in @Table, the column view_id is unique and on auto-increment.

and I have an interface as follows:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.List;


@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ViewDao extends CrudRepository<View, Integer> {

    View findByWidgetIdAndRetailerAndViewLabel(int widgetId,String retailer,String viewLabel);

    List<View> findAllByWidgetId(int widgetId);

    View findByWidgetIdAndRetailer(int widgetId,String retailer);

    @Query(value = "select max(viewId) from View")
    Integer getMaxViewId();

    List<View> findByViewNameIn(List<String> viewNames);

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update view set widget_id = :widgetId where view_name = :viewName", nativeQuery = true)
    void updateBYViewName(@Param("widgetId") int widgetId, @Param("viewName") String viewName);

}
```

Now when I am trying to make an updation to the above entity by the following line:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Response personalizeDashboardViews(Map<WidgetPersonalizeAction, List<View>> personalizedViews, DashboardAction dashboardAction, RequestParams requestParams, int pageId) {
        Response response = new Response();

        if (null != personalizedViews && !personalizedViews.isEmpty()){
            for (Map.Entry<WidgetPersonalizeAction,List<View>> personalizeActionListEntry : personalizedViews.entrySet()){
                if (personalizeActionListEntry.getKey().equals(WidgetPersonalizeAction.UPDATE) ||
                        personalizeActionListEntry.getKey().equals(WidgetPersonalizeAction.DELETE)){
                    //Delete the existing views
                    viewDao.deleteAll(personalizeActionListEntry.getValue());
                    //create the personalized views
                    viewDao.saveAll(personalizeActionListEntry.getValue()); //issue is here
                    response.setMessage("Views successfully updated");
                }else if (personalizeActionListEntry.getKey().equals(WidgetPersonalizeAction.REORDER_UPDATE)){
                    List<View> viewList = personalizeActionListEntry.getValue();
                    for (View view:viewList){
                        viewDao.updateBYViewName(view.getWidgetId(), view.getViewName());
                    }
                } else if (personalizeActionListEntry.getKey().equals(WidgetPersonalizeAction.CLONE)){
                    viewDao.saveAll(personalizeActionListEntry.getValue());
                    response.setMessage("News view successfully created");
                }else {
                    response.setMessage(personalizeActionListEntry.getKey()+" invalid view personalize action");
                    break;
                }

            }
            response.setSuccess(true);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

I get an error as:

```
ERROR
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [View#0]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [View#0]
```

This error does not come on each updation, but only on a few specific view_id updations. Please help.